# How do I make jQuery statement execute after .load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the possibly terrible question title. I don't know how to word it properly. Please offer suggestions.

Anyhoo, I have this html:

```
<ul class="image_reel">
<li class="thin"><a href="#" rel="img14" title="Click to view"><img   class="gal_thumb" src="8681.jpg"></a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#" rel="img0" title="Click to view"><img class="gal_thumb" src="DSC_7586.jpg"></a></li>
<li class="thin"><a href="#" rel="img2" title="Click to view"><img class="gal_thumb" src="DSC_7601.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to assign the li either a 'thick' or 'thin' class based on the height of the child img. So I have this jQuery:

```
 // add 'thin' class to parent li
 jQuery('.image_reel li a img').load( 
    function() {
            var t = jQuery(this);
            var h = this.naturalHeight;
            if( h < 800 ) {
                jQuery(t).parent().parent().addClass( 'thin' );
            }
 });                    

 // now sort lis
 var $images = jQuery('.image_reel');
 var $imagesli = $images.children('li');
 $imagesli.sort(function(a,b){
        var aT = jQuery(a).hasClass('thin');
        var bT = jQuery(b).hasClass('thin');
        if( aT == true && ( bT == false )  )
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
 });
 $imagesli.detach().appendTo($images);
```

The problem seems to be that the first block seems to execute -after- the second block. Or maybe they execute synchronously? Regardless, the code doesn't work. So... how do I make the first block of code execute -before- the 2nd?

The weird thing is that, if I use the Firefox 'Q' debugger, the code actually 'works'. But without the debugger it doesn't. I assume that the debugger forces the code to run in some sort of special order.

Comment: it appears the syntax of your .load function is incorrect. You are missing the document or url to be loaded and only has the callback function defined.

Comment: @DinoMyte He's using the shorthand of the [`.on('load', callback)`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) version, not the [ajax shorthand](http://api.jquery.com/load/). So his syntax is actually correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your section block in a function, and then call it after the load function ends, like put it in the return

```
// add 'thin' class to parent li
jQuery('.image_reel li a img').load(function() {
    var t = jQuery(this);
    var h = this.naturalHeight;
    if( h < 800 ) {
        jQuery(t).parent().parent().addClass( 'thin' );
    }
    return loadBlock();
});                    

function loadBlock() {
    // now sort lis
    var $images = jQuery('.image_reel');
    var $imagesli = $images.children('li');
    $imagesli.sort(function(a,b){
        var aT = jQuery(a).hasClass('thin');
        var bT = jQuery(b).hasClass('thin');
        if( aT == true && ( bT == false ) ) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });

    $imagesli.detach().appendTo($images);       
}
```

Or use a package like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) `.waterfall` or `.series`

---

You can use something like async as I mentioned above to have better flow control over async functions here's an example on how you could avoid calling on every callback

```
async.each($("img"), function(e, callback) {
   $(this).load(function() {
      console.log("bdbdbd");
      callback(); // Done loading image
   });
}, function() {
   console.log("Done loading images");
   loadBlock();
});
```

Async package can and will be your best friend if utilized properly.

I'm on mobile so I can't really test but this worked just fine on jsbin just throw your code in there and it should work.

this works because when you call `jQuery('.image_reel li a img').load` this will run its own loop on every element it finds and attach the event listener to it.

The method I used was I used `async.each` which takes an array, in this case I provided $('#img') as the array which will be a collection of any element it finds that matches the query, then `async.each` will run the loops in parallel so we don't have to wait for one to finish before the loop can proceed to the next thing.

Then in the loop body we call `.load` on `.this` which is attaching the `.load` function on only 1 element at a time and not trying to do its own internal loop on all the elements, so this way when the function completes we know that its done cause that function is only running on on element. Then we call `callback();` which is required for `async.each` to let `.each` know that the function body is done and it can proceed, when all loops trigger their `callback` the loop ends and then the main function executes (the function that's the third argument to `.each`). You can see more about async.each here: [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each)

Comment: Thanks. This 'works'. However, it's horribly slow... I guess since the loadBlock() runs for every li element. Is there any way (other than incrementing a counter in the .load() function so it only executes on the last element? That works, but it seems inelegant. Is there a better solution?

Comment: @jchwebdev see my edit. Unfortunately using .load on a selector just runs its own internal loop and has no way of knowing when the internal loop is done. So either use a counter or do something like I suggested above.

Comment: @jchwebdev did this end up helping yoi?

Comment: It does help. Can you help me understand -why- .load() runs to completion before any other tasks. Can you recommend a tut or other docs on this?

Comment: @jchwebdev I added a bit of an explanation though I'm not sure if I made it very understandable

Answer (score 1):

The second block executes before the first block because the `load()` resolves immediately and only calls the first block later when it has finished. To do what you want, call the second block at the end of the first block.

```
// add 'thin' class to parent li
 jQuery('.image_reel li a img').load( 
    function() {
            var t = jQuery(this);
            var h = this.naturalHeight;
            if( h < 800 ) {
                jQuery(t).parent().parent().addClass( 'thin' );
            }
            doWork();
 });                    

function doWork() {
 // now sort lis
 var $images = jQuery('.image_reel');
 var $imagesli = $images.children('li');
 $imagesli.sort(function(a,b){
        var aT = jQuery(a).hasClass('thin');
        var bT = jQuery(b).hasClass('thin');
        if( aT == true && ( bT == false )  )
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
 });
 $imagesli.detach().appendTo($images); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I obviously need to understand -why- .load() runs to completion before any other tasks. Can you recommend a tut or other docs on this?